# Reading and printing from a file

Tags: c, file-io

I'm trying to get a single character from a file i made, however when i try to run this code, it crashes. I've tried modeling my code after other examples but it doesn't seem to work. Is it an issue with my file name? My code is in the same folder as PPM.txt, and PPM  has various random numbers separated with spaces and newlines in it

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("PPM.txt", "r");
char x = fgetc(fp);
printf("%s hi \n", x);
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Check your `printf` format specifier.

Comment: Enable compilers warnings to save time and detect simple issues as in `char x = fgetc(fp);
printf("%s hi \n", x);`

Comment: fgetc() returns `int` which might hold the value of an `unsigne char`. Use `int`, convert to `unsigned char` after checking for `EOF`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `%c` instead of `%s`.

```
printf("%c hi\n", x);
```

`%s` expects a null-terminated string, whereas `%c` looks for a single character.

Comment: omg thanks so silly of me